# An Entity Framework equivalent for .Net Compact Edition?

Tags: entity-framework, compact-framework

Since Entity Framework does not run in .Net Compact Edition is there any compatible alternatives I can take a look at?

*I'm especially looking for something I can use on Windows Mobile 6.1.

Comment: Why would anybody want to use junk like Entity Framework anyway?   http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2008/05/19/why-use-the-entity-framework-yeah-why-exactly.aspx    http://efvote.wufoo.com/forms/ado-net-entity-framework-vote-of-no-confidence/

Comment: No. Moreover Windows Mobile 6.x is dead platform. Even MS is discontinuing related services like market place.

Comment: @Ladislav - it's not dead.  It was renamed to Windows Embedded Handheld, and is still being used for many LOB and ruggedized devices.  There are plenty of reasons to still use it - it's just no longer a consumer-focused product.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka harharhar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "compatible".  You mean a compatible object model?  Nothing that I'm aware of, but then EF is huge and if you found something it would probably perform terrible anyway.  If you're simply after an ORM that can be used on multiple platforms, [the OpenNETCF ORM](http://orm.codeplex.com) works fine under Windows Mobile and Windows desktop (plus Mono for iOS and Android to boot).  In fact it was first written for Windows CE, so it works rather well for WinMo.